# Bootstrap list-group not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone please explain to me why isn't this code working? I get regular list items instead of Bootstrap ones...

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you'll need to provide a bit more detail.  What exactly is the problem?  Is it that the items are not styled?  Are you sure the boostrap css file is being included in your page?

Comment: You are including the bootstrap CSS right? Open your browser console and check for errors that might indicate that Bootstrap's CSS isn't loading properly

Comment: I just realized what the problem was... I didn't know that list-groups were implemented in version 3... I was using an old version...

Comment: Might want to answer your own question then to help others ?

Comment: I will... I have to wait 8 hours before i can do that...

Comment: ... and he never did. What ever happened to you user1176999 ?

Comment: @Chris I just did, sorry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just realized what the problem was... I didn't know that list-groups were implemented in version 3... I was using an old version...

Comment: And user1176999 returns!